# Meteorjs - undefined function for ignite ui plugin

Tags: meteor

Getting the following error

Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
<head>
<title>Orion</title>
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2014.2/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2014.2/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <!-- JavaScript Library Dependencies -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>

<!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2014.2/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2014.2/latest/js/infragistics.dv.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2014.2/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js">   </script>
</head>

<template name="currencyData">
<div class="container">
<div id="gridChartContainer">
<table id="grid"></table>

</div>
</div>
```

```
Template.currencyData.rendered = function() {
if (this.find("#grid")) console.log("Found the grid");

this.find("#grid").igGrid({
width: "100%",
dataSource: currencyData,
autoGenerateColumns: true,
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue with the calls...

Modified my function to look as below

```
Template.currencyData.rendered = function() {
this.$("#grid").igGrid({
 width: "80%",
 dataSource: currencyData,
 autoGenerateColumns: true,
});
}
```